# Выезжающий фиксированный блок внутри контента

Tags: css, css3

Внутри блока с основным контентом нужна фиксированная кнопка при нажатии по которой будет выезжать div блок и этот блок должен растягивается по все высоте экрана. Внешне это я реализовал вот так [Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/Angel_33_3/k6m7tnv6/)

Проблема в том, что сейчас блок `fixed-block`, который поверх всего, перекрывает контент и не позволяет взаимодействовать с ним.

Может кто-то подскажет как избежать это проблемы и внешне оставить все так же?

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 520px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.fixed-block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  max-width: 520px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.hidden-block {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: right .2s;
}
.hidden-block-ticker {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  hieght: 50px;
  background-color: #3da7a6;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: right .23s;
}
.btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #001414;
}
.btn:hover {
  right: 10px;
}
.btn:hover + .hidden-block {
  right: -190px;
}
.hidden-block-ticker:checked ~ .btn {
  right: 200px;
}
.hidden-block-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-block {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn" class="hidden-block-ticker">
    <label class="btn" for="btn">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <div class="hidden-block">
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в z-index. Поставь z-index, равный z-index'у контента и усе.

Comment: Перенесите код из ссылки прямо в вопрос.

Comment: z-index тут не поможет, даже если для div content поставить большее значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то будет полезно, решение нашел через pointer-events. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Angel_33_3/pj8n4jhn/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn" class="hidden-block-ticker">
    <label class="btn" for="btn">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <div class="hidden-block">
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
      <p>fgfdfdgfdg</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
    <p>Sasasas</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 520px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.fixed-block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  max-width: 520px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.hidden-block {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: right .2s;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.hidden-block-ticker {
  display: none;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  hieght: 50px;
  background-color: #3da7a6;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: right .23s;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #001414;
}
.btn:hover {
  right: 10px;
}
.btn:hover + .hidden-block {
  right: -190px;
}
.hidden-block-ticker:checked ~ .btn {
  right: 200px;
}
.hidden-block-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-block {
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас этот блок занимает 100% ширины, поэтому он перехватывает управление. Вам нужно задать его ширину фиксировано.

например вот так

```
.fixed-block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  max-width: 520px;
  width: 300px;     /* изменил */
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;         /* добавил */
}
```

Comment: в таком случае кнопка, вытягивающая скрытый блок, пристанет к правому краю браузер